# Why could bookdown not produce images in outputted html?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Recently, I wrote a Chinese version report using bookdown.
I set the `yaml` of `index.rmd` as below:

```
---
title: "My Chinese words title"
output: 
  Grmd::docx_document: 
    fig_caption: TRUE
    force_captions: TRUE
    dev: cairo_pdf
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
---
```

And `_output.yml` file was setting as below:

```
Grmd::docx_document: 
    fig_caption: TRUE
    force_captions: TRUE
    dev: cairo_pdf
    new_session: true
```

All things above were setting simply.

And I tried to build bookdown. The procedures was okay and successfully produced several files. What I need is a file names `_mail.html`. However, when I opened it , everything could be display correctly including text and tables besides pictures. You can look at the pictures I show below. The picture's parts is generated with `ggplot2` plotting:

```
df.raw.ls1 %>% ggplot(aes(factor(pesticide),ladybeetles   ))+geom_boxplot()+
  geom_point( position = position_jitter(width=0.1))+
  facet_wrap(YEAR~.)


p1 <- df.raw %>% ggplot(aes(SHDI,ladybeetles   #,label=SITES
                      ))+
  geom_point( aes(color=SITES) )+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
 # geom_text(aes(color=SITES))+
  facet_grid(YEAR~SCALE,scales = "free")


p2 <- df.raw %>% ggplot(aes(tree,ladybeetles   #,label=SITES
                      ))+
  geom_point( aes(color=SITES) )+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
 # geom_text(aes(color=SITES))+
  facet_grid(YEAR~SCALE,scales = "free")


p3 <- df.raw %>% ggplot(aes(grass,ladybeetles   #,label=SITES
                      ))+
  geom_point( aes(color=SITES) )+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
 # geom_text(aes(color=SITES))+
  facet_grid(YEAR~SCALE,scales = "free")

library(patchwork)
 p1/p2/p3 + plot_layout(ncol = 1,guides = "collect")
```

[image]
[image]

**You also can see the images were surely generated at this path here**:
`D:\NewProcedure2021\Rmarkdown\_bookdown_files\_main_files\figure-html`
[image]

**Apart from these, I also set the `knitr` options**:

```
# main path
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir="D:/NewProcedure2021/Rmarkdown/")

knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning=FALSE,
                      message=FALSE,
                      echo=FALSE,
                      dpi=40,  #
                      out.width=550,out.height=400, 
                      fig.width=12, fig.height=8,  
                      fig.align="center",
                      dev="png", dev.args=list(type="cairo"), # The png device
                      # Change to dev="postscript" if you want the EPS-files
                      # for submitting. Also remove the dev.args() as the postscript
                      # doesn't accept the type="cairo" argument.
                      error=FALSE)

# Evaluate the figure caption after the plot
knitr::opts_knit$set(eval.after='fig.cap')


# Use the table counter that the htmlTable() provides
options(table_counter = TRUE)

# Use the figCapNo() with roman letters
options(fig_caption_no_roman = TRUE)
```

**So, I want to somebody could help me know how to resolve the problem that pictures generated by the `ggplot2` could not display at the right position.** I think it's not simply using `include_graphics()` or `<img src="">` methods. What I wish is the pictures could be automatically putting and showing in the correct position for ggplot's pictures. If the `yaml` file or `yaml` header in `index.rmd` or `knitr chunks` or `knitr options` could be set, it will be nice. But I don't know the appropriate code at there.

Thanks everyone who cares about my question, sincerely!  Look forward to your answers.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? #askingforafriend